# Differences between Spring ResponseBody's ObjectMapper and Jackson's ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, marshalling

Is there any difference between the internal marshaller that Spring use to serialize an Object into JSON and the Jackson's ObjectMapper serializer ?

Comment: The marshaller uses jackson, so why would there be a difference?

Comment: Spring uses a configurable converter, and the default one for JSON is Jackson (specifically usually `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`).